# Saving to-do list items in the browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I want my to-do list project data to be saved in browser. The list which I have made so far should not be erased on reloading the page.

I have searched for a solution to this, but all are saying about storing in a database. If possible can I do it from browser?

```
$(window).on('unload', function() {
  saveSettings();
  loadSettings();
});
```

I have tried this after searching from the internet but didn't get up any solutions.

Comment: You could use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: See also this, found for Googling 'todo list localstorage' https://codepen.io/ragzor/pen/xGrJrg